# updating data to/from two identical tables using SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have two tables, lets say `table_a` and `table_b`, both have same schema/structure.

```
table_a(
id int,
name nvarchar(50)
)

table_b(
id int,
name nvarchar(50)
)
```

Now I want to update `table_a(name)` from `table_b(name)`, wherever id matches.

How can I do it?

Comment: Google *SQL Server update join*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `join` in an `update`.  The specific syntax varies by database.  In SQL Server, it looks like:

```
update a
    set name = b.name
    from table_a a join
         table_b b
         on a.id = b.id;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code. Ask Questions after search in Google.

```
UPDATE table_a
    SET table_a.NAME = table_b.NAME
FROM table_a A, table_b B
WHERE A.ID = B.ID
```